# What is the best method to reading in a file in Android word by word

Tags: java, android, file-io, java.util.scanner, fileinputstream

I'm looking to read in a text file in my app but I need to read it in word by word rather than line by line. I'm used to Java and the Scanner class with the hasNext() method so I am currently using that. Here is my code:

```
        try
    {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILENAME);
        Scanner infile = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        while(infile.hasNext())
        {
            accName = infile.next();
            uName = infile.next();
            pWord = infile.next();

            ((ArrayHandler)getApplicationContext()).info.add(new Information(accName, uName, pWord));

            for( int i = 0; i < ((ArrayHandler)getApplicationContext()).info.size(); i++)
            {

            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception err)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Could Not Read File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

If there is another way that either better please let me know. Also, this file is not created until the app is actually used, so it'll throw the error first and then after onDestroy() occurs and the user reloads the information it will read it.

**EDIT**
Sorry for the non responsive reply until now. But the method shown above is actually 100% working. So for those looking to read a file in word by word and assign them (like above) this code works without any issue.

Comment: Not sure what is your purpose actually. Please explain it a bit. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: What are your words seperated by?  Commas?

Comment: Could you just read the file line by line, and read each line you get word by word? Are you expecting an account name, user name, and password all on one line? If that's the case then I think it would be a simple matter of doing a single readline, then splitting the string you get by spaces and using the substrings for those values. Or you could put them on separate lines in the file and just do three readlines. Like Abdul said, a little clarification would help, unless I'm right in my assumption.

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse line by line and pick up the lines matching a pattern (three words with spaces):

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)");
    Scanner sc = null;
    try {
        sc = new Scanner(getAssets().open("test.txt"));
        while (sc.hasNextLine()){
            Matcher m  = p.matcher(sc.nextLine());
            if(m.find()){
                Log.i("TESTING","Account:"+m.group(1)+", User:"+m.group(2)+", Password:"+m.group(3));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```